# How to update listview during search

Tags: java, android, listview

This is my app when I start it:

When I click one of the item in the list view it will open a new activity and display some data.

When I search for something it looks like this:

And when I click an item in the list it starts a new activity. But the activity it starts is not accurate.

Here's my code:

**HomeActivity.class**

```
package com.thesis.herbalmedicines.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity implements
        SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    ListView lv;
    SearchView search;

    String[] herb_names, sample_arr; //= ["Boils","",""];//, iso_codes;
    TypedArray herb_pics;

    ArrayList<Home> homelist;
    HomeAdapter adapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.home_layout, frameLayout);

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(listArray[position]);

        android.app.ActionBar ab = getActionBar(); 
        ColorDrawable colorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#50B222"));     
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);


        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        search = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);

        herb_names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.herb_names);
        //iso_codes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.iso_Code);
        herb_pics = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.herb_pics);

        homelist = new ArrayList<Home>();
        for (int i = 0; i < herb_names.length; i++) {
            Home home = new Home(herb_names[i], //iso_codes[i],
                    herb_pics.getResourceId(i, -1));
            homelist.add(home);
        }

        adapter = new HomeAdapter(getApplicationContext(), homelist);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                if (position == 0) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Boils.class);
                    startActivity(a);

                    /** Fading Transition Effect */
                    HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }

                else if (position == 1) {
                    Intent b = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Cystitis.class);
                    startActivity(b);

                    /** Fading Transition Effect */
                    HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }

                else if (position == 2) {
                    Intent c = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Asthma.class);
                    startActivity(c);

                    /** Fading Transition Effect */
                    HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }
                else if (position == 3) {
                    Intent d = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Feet.class);
                    startActivity(d);

                    /** Fading Transition Effect */
                    HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }



            }
        });
        search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }



}
```

**Home.java**

```
package com.thesis.herbalmedicines.activity;

public class Home {

    String name;
    int pics;
    Home(String name, int pics) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pics = pics;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPics() {
        return pics;
    }

    public void setPics(int pics) {
        this.pics = pics;
    }

}
```

**HomeAdapter.java**

```
package com.thesis.herbalmedicines.activity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HomeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Home> homelist;
    ArrayList<Home> mStringFilterList;
    ValueFilter valueFilter;

    HomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Home> homelist) {
        this.context = context;
        this.homelist = homelist;
        mStringFilterList = homelist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return homelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return homelist.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return homelist.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

            TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

            Home home = homelist.get(position);

            name_tv.setText(home.getName());
            iv.setImageResource(home.getPics());
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (valueFilter == null) {
            valueFilter = new ValueFilter();
        }
        return valueFilter;
    }

    private class ValueFilter extends Filter {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0) {
                ArrayList<Home> filterList = new ArrayList<Home>();
                for (int i = 0; i < mStringFilterList.size(); i++) {
                    if ((mStringFilterList.get(i).getName().toUpperCase())
                            .contains(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {

                        Home home = new Home(mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getName(), mStringFilterList.get(i)
                                .getPics());

                        filterList.add(home);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filterList.size();
                results.values = filterList;
            } else {
                results.count = mStringFilterList.size();
                results.values = mStringFilterList;
            }
            return results;

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            homelist = (ArrayList<Home>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: have you used notifyDataSetChanged() http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example

Comment: Yes I did. I update my code. Please check ..

Comment: What is your result? Which activity opened?

Comment: Can you explain `But the activity it starts is not accurate.` a bit? Are you able to predict which activity will be started?

Comment: Sorry for not eplaining my self very well.

Comment: Lets say. instead it shows activity one. It shows activity two. Hmm. In the home in the first image, when I click the first title the activity it starts is what I want to start. But when the user search for a keyword, and click the very first result for example, it shows a different content. Which is not what I want to be display ..

Comment: `if (position == 0) {
                    Intent a = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Boils.class);
                    startActivity(a);

                    /** Fading Transition Effect */
                    HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                }`

Comment: I hope this will make myself even more clear. https://youtu.be/Pl7nvH5bRvQ

Comment: you are doing it all wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field that holds the class to be loaded inside the `Home` class. (The `id` field is optional)

```
public class Home {
    int id;
    String name;
    int pics;
    Class clazz;

    Home(int id, String name, int pics, Class clazz) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.pics = pics;
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
    // getters and setters
}
```

During initialization of the `homelist` add the `id`,

```
// the classed to load
Class[] classes = {
    Boils.class,
    Cystitis.class,
    Asthma.class,
    Feet.class
};

for (int i = 0; i < herb_names.length; i++) {
    Home home = new Home(i, herb_names[i], herb_pics.getResourceId(i, -1), classes[i]);
    homelist.add(home);
}
```

Inside the `setOnItemClickListener`,

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,  int position, long id) {

        Home item = (Home) adapter.getItem(position);

        Intent d = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, item.getClazz());
        startActivity(d);

        /** Fading Transition Effect */
        HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }
});
```

Couple of changes should be made in your adapter as well.

Inside the `getView` you are forcing the `convertView` to null. It is bad for performance. (Consider using a `ViewHolder` too)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    TextView name_tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pic);

    Home home = homelist.get(position);

    name_tv.setText(home.getName());
    iv.setImageResource(home.getPics());

    return convertView;
}
```

Inside `publishResults` you are creating a new reference for the dataset. You should update the existing dataset.

```
@Override
protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,  FilterResults results) {
    homelist.clear();
    homelist.addAll((ArrayList<Home>) results.values);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I have done what you have said, it shows no error in eclipse(IDE that I'm using) but when I start the app, it shows the unfortunately stop message. How can I fix this.?

Comment: Heres the link of my updated files, 1. [Home.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQrW6aKuoE1Ym0xU0U4NUJKM0E/view?usp=sharing) 2. [HomeActivity.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQrW6aKuoE1TWxCMkhYNjJqZm8/view?usp=sharing) 3. [HomeAdapter.java](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxQrW6aKuoE1T2xuZU0wa3pmREU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is my logcat      [logcat1pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxQrW6aKuoE1bkR6eFNLc0o1ZFE)   logcat [logcat2pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxQrW6aKuoE1NDdHV3lldDBzU3c)

Comment: Make sure `herb_names` and `classes` have same length! So that each herb has an `Activity` to display.

Answer (score 0):

Set adpter to listview on every onSerch

Comment: Just watch this video , this is much  clear about my problem of my app .https://youtu.be/Pl7nvH5bRvQ

Comment: try without implementing your class as SearchView.OnQueryTextListener

Comment: int your onQueryTextChange method change return false to true.

Comment: Same result  return false to true

Comment: I think there is an problem in yiur approach. Just add simple textview and set textChangeListner write yourAdapter.getFilters().filter (string);

Comment: how ? what specific part ?

Comment: It will automatically update your adapter. As my knowladge when you click on the item, you pick the values from old listview. Simply place a break point to item click event see what yor receiving form item click

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use position to navigate to different activity ?

```
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            if (position == 0) {
                Intent a = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Boils.class);
                startActivity(a);

                /** Fading Transition Effect */
                HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            }

            else if (position == 1) {
                Intent b = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Cystitis.class);
                startActivity(b);

                /** Fading Transition Effect */
                HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            }

            else if (position == 2) {
                Intent c = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Asthma.class);
                startActivity(c);

                /** Fading Transition Effect */
                HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            }
            else if (position == 3) {
                Intent d = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, Feet.class);
                startActivity(d);

                /** Fading Transition Effect */
                HomeActivity.this.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            }



        }
    });
    search.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
}
```

This will always reset your position whenever you adapter refresh from search result.

To do this in better way. Just create custom listener like following in your adapter.

```
Public interface ListViewClick{
  void onListClick(Object type)
}
```

Register your receiver in activity and pass type of activity to launch from adapter

```
  private ListViewClick callback;
  HomeAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Home> homelist,ListViewClick callback) {
        this.context = context;
        this.homelist = homelist;
        mStringFilterList = homelist;
        this.callback = callback;
    }
```

and on click listener of `convertView` pass `callback.onListClick(//type of activity to launch)`.

Just keep reference of 'type of activity to launch in Home enitity'. so you can recognize which activity is ti be launch when clicking on particular row of list view.